# I cannot open my docker container in my browser?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image

I've created an image on my local with my IdentityServer project.

Simply , I did build my dockerfile using

```
docker build -t identityserver .
```

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY /IdentityServer/*.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY /IdentityServer ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IdentityServer.dll"]
```

Then after the build, I did run the image in the container

```
docker run -d -p 5443:5443 <image_id>
```

THE PROBLEM IS:
I'm trying to connect with the container using https://localhost:5443 but it doesn't work. The site cannot be reach. It is not existing. I've tried to look on the logs (see below) except that I think it runs in a production environment. I pretty sure it is one to fix because I'm just running in my local. But why can't I even find the page in the browser?

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app/
```

Comment: the thing inside the container is listening on port 80, according to the logs.  So you need to fix the port mapping `-p 5443:80`.

Answer (score 3):

because your application is running on 80 port inside container.

Now listening on: http://[::]:80

you should map your local 5443 port to container 80 port.

```
docker run -d -p 5443:80 <image_id>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I know why there are two ports.